# Save.image() responds with Error in gzfile

Tags: r

I am somewhat new to R which is why I am still experimenting with some basic stuff.

Currently, I am stuck with the `save.image()` function. Whenever I try:

```
save.image("Macintosh HD/User/Name/Documents/docname.RData")
```

I am receiving an error message:

> Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In file.remove(outfile) :
>     cannot remove file '/Benutzer/Julius/Dokumente/MBD/myfile.RDataTmp', reason 'No such file or directory'
>   2: In gzfile(file, "wb") :
>     cannot open compressed file 'Macintosh/Benutzer/Julius/Dokumente/MBD/myfile.RDataTmp', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

I am unsure how to resolve the issue.

Comment: What errors (if any) does `save.image("~/Documents/docname.RData")` generate?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! 
To understand this command better: What exactly does "~" express?

Comment: `~` is shorthand for the home directory of the current user and you can reference any relative path from it via `~/some/path/to/file.whatev`. To see what it resolves to you can use `path.expand("~/whatever/path/you/specify")`. Your issue was that even though "Get Info" (what you likely used to derive that long path you used) shows the path spec in macOS canonical form vs the POSIX path spec that R requires.

Comment: thank you @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 0):

`~` is shorthand for the home directory of the current user and you can reference any relative path from it via `~/some/path/to/file.whatev`. To see what it resolves to you can use `path.expand("~/whatever/path/you/specify")`.

Your issue was that even though "Get Info" (what you likely used to derive that long path you used) shows the path spec in macOS canonical form vs the POSIX path spec that R requires.